# Turning off sanitizer for bootstrap

Tags: 7, bootstrap-theme

My javascript popovers are breaking here and there. When I searched for the solution, I came to a conclusion that I need to disable the sanitizer. I could not find a line for it in the `bootstrap.js` file (below).

```
/**
 * @file
 * bootstrap.js
 *
 * Provides general enhancements and fixes to Bootstrap's JS files.
 */

var Drupal = Drupal || {};

(function($, Drupal){
  "use strict";

  var $document = $(document);

  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrap = {
    attach: function(context) {
      // Provide some Bootstrap tab/Drupal integration.
      $(context).find('.tabbable').once('bootstrap-tabs', function () {
        var $wrapper = $(this);
        var $tabs = $wrapper.find('.nav-tabs');
        var $content = $wrapper.find('.tab-content');
        var borderRadius = parseInt($content.css('borderBottomRightRadius'), 10);
        var bootstrapTabResize = function() {
          if ($wrapper.hasClass('tabs-left') || $wrapper.hasClass('tabs-right')) {
            $content.css('min-height', $tabs.outerHeight());
          }
        };
        // Add min-height on content for left and right tabs.
        bootstrapTabResize();
        // Detect tab switch.
        if ($wrapper.hasClass('tabs-left') || $wrapper.hasClass('tabs-right')) {
          $tabs.on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
            bootstrapTabResize();
            if ($wrapper.hasClass('tabs-left')) {
              if ($(e.target).parent().is(':first-child')) {
                $content.css('borderTopLeftRadius', '0');
              }
              else {
                $content.css('borderTopLeftRadius', borderRadius + 'px');
              }
            }
            else {
              if ($(e.target).parent().is(':first-child')) {
                $content.css('borderTopRightRadius', '0');
              }
              else {
                $content.css('borderTopRightRadius', borderRadius + 'px');
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

  /**
   * Behavior for .
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapFormHasError = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (settings.bootstrap && settings.bootstrap.formHasError) {
        var $context = $(context);
        $context.find('.form-item.has-error:not(.form-type-password.has-feedback)').once('error', function () {
          var $formItem = $(this);
          var $input = $formItem.find(':input');
          $input.on('keyup focus blur', function () {
            var value = $input.val() || false;
            $formItem[value ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('has-error');
            $input[value ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('error');
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };

  /**
   * Bootstrap Popovers.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapPopovers = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // Immediately return if popovers are not available.
      if (!settings.bootstrap || !settings.bootstrap.popoverEnabled || !$.fn.popover) {
        return;
      }

      // Popover autoclose.
      if (settings.bootstrap.popoverOptions.triggerAutoclose) {
        var $currentPopover = null;
        $document
          .on('show.bs.popover', '[data-toggle=popover]', function () {
            var $trigger = $(this);
            var popover = $trigger.data('bs.popover');

            // Only keep track of clicked triggers that we're manually handling.
            if (popover.options.originalTrigger === 'click') {
              if ($currentPopover && !$currentPopover.is($trigger)) {
                $currentPopover.popover('hide');
              }
              $currentPopover = $trigger;
            }
          })
          .on('click', function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            var popover = $target.is('[data-toggle=popover]') && $target.data('bs.popover');
            if ($currentPopover && !$target.is('[data-toggle=popover]') && !$target.closest('.popover.in')[0]) {
              $currentPopover.popover('hide');
              $currentPopover = null;
            }
          })
        ;
      }

      var elements = $(context).find('[data-toggle=popover]').toArray();
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var $element = $(elements[i]);
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS, settings.bootstrap.popoverOptions, $element.data());

        // Store the original trigger.
        options.originalTrigger = options.trigger;

        // If the trigger is "click", then we'll handle it manually here.
        if (options.trigger === 'click') {
          options.trigger = 'manual';
        }

        // Retrieve content from a target element.
        var target = options.target || $element.is('a[href^="#"]') && $element.attr('href');
        var $target = $document.find(target).clone();
        if (!options.content && $target[0]) {
          $target.removeClass('element-invisible hidden').removeAttr('aria-hidden');
          options.content = $target.wrap('<div/>').parent()[options.html ? 'html' : 'text']() || '';
        }

        // Initialize the popover.
        $element.popover(options);

        // Handle clicks manually.
        if (options.originalTrigger === 'click') {
          // To ensure the element is bound multiple times, remove any
          // previously set event handler before adding another one.
          $element
            .off('click.drupal.bootstrap.popover')
            .on('click.drupal.bootstrap.popover', function (e) {
              $(this).popover('toggle');
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
            })
          ;
        }
      }
    },
    detach: function (context, settings) {
      // Immediately return if popovers are not available.
      if (!settings.bootstrap || !settings.bootstrap.popoverEnabled || !$.fn.popover) {
        return;
      }

      // Destroy all popovers.
      $(context).find('[data-toggle="popover"]')
        .off('click.drupal.bootstrap.popover')
        .popover('destroy')
      ;
    }
  };

  /**
   * Bootstrap Tooltips.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapTooltips = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (settings.bootstrap && settings.bootstrap.tooltipEnabled) {
        var elements = $(context).find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').toArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          var $element = $(elements[i]);
          var options = $.extend({}, settings.bootstrap.tooltipOptions, $element.data());
          $element.tooltip(options);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  /**
   * Anchor fixes.
   */
  var $scrollableElement = $();
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapAnchors = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var i, elements = ['html', 'body'];
      if (!$scrollableElement.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          var $element = $(elements[i]);
          if ($element.scrollTop() > 0) {
            $scrollableElement = $element;
            break;
          }
          else {
            $element.scrollTop(1);
            if ($element.scrollTop() > 0) {
              $element.scrollTop(0);
              $scrollableElement = $element;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!settings.bootstrap || settings.bootstrap.anchorsFix !== '1') {
        return;
      }
      var anchors = $(context).find('a').toArray();
      for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        if (!anchors[i].scrollTo) {
          this.bootstrapAnchor(anchors[i]);
        }
      }
      $scrollableElement.once('bootstrap-anchors', function () {
        $scrollableElement.on('click.bootstrap-anchors', 'a[href*="#"]:not([data-toggle],[data-target],[data-slide])', function(e) {
          if (this.scrollTo) {
            this.scrollTo(e);
          }
        });
      });
    },
    bootstrapAnchor: function (element) {
      element.validAnchor = element.nodeName === 'A' && (location.hostname === element.hostname || !element.hostname) && (element.hash.replace(/#/,'').length > 0);
      element.scrollTo = function(event) {
        var attr = 'id';
        var $target = $(element.hash);
        // Check for anchors that use the name attribute instead.
        if (!$target.length) {
          attr = 'name';
          $target = $('[name="' + element.hash.replace('#', '') + '"]');
        }
        // Immediately stop if no anchors are found.
        if (!this.validAnchor && !$target.length) {
          return;
        }
        // Anchor is valid, continue if there is an offset.
        var offset = $target.offset().top - parseInt($scrollableElement.css('paddingTop'), 10) - parseInt($scrollableElement.css('marginTop'), 10);
        if (offset > 0) {
          if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          var $fakeAnchor = $('<div/>')
            .addClass('element-invisible')
            .attr(attr, $target.attr(attr))
            .css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: offset + 'px',
              zIndex: -1000
            })
            .appendTo($scrollableElement);
          $target.removeAttr(attr);
          var complete = function () {
            location.hash = element.hash;
            $fakeAnchor.remove();
            $target.attr(attr, element.hash.replace('#', ''));
          };
          if (Drupal.settings.bootstrap.anchorsSmoothScrolling) {
            $scrollableElement.animate({ scrollTop: offset, avoidTransforms: true }, 400, complete);
          }
          else {
            $scrollableElement.scrollTop(offset);
            complete();
          }
        }
      };
    }
  };

  /**
   * Tabledrag theming elements.
   */
  Drupal.theme.tableDragChangedMarker = function () {
    return '<span class="tabledrag-changed glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign text-warning"></span>';
  };

  Drupal.theme.tableDragChangedWarning = function () {
    return '<div class="tabledrag-changed-warning alert alert-warning messages warning">' + Drupal.theme('tableDragChangedMarker') + ' ' + Drupal.t('Changes made in this table will not be saved until the form is submitted.') + '</div>';
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: can someone please explain why this question received -1 reputation points. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: What bootstrap.js file are your referring to? Is this a custom file? Or contrib? What sanitizer? Sanitizing what? We also can't coach you on reading code. It's a too broad request. You need to learn that yourself. The question also is missing the steps to reproduce it. `Popovers breaking here and there` is an absolutely unclear information. Last but not least Bootstrap and the Drupal Bootstrap theme is considered third-party. You may raise a support issue in its issue queue, but not here. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request to a third-party theme and may be answered in this theme's issue queue on drupal.org instead with sufficient info to reproduce it.

Comment: I posted this question under Drupal Answers, selected the tags for `7` and `bootstrap-theme`. Bootstrap theme does not come with core. If it were a custom file, I would have specified it too, this is the `bootstrap.js` file that comes with that package. I would like to turn off sanitizer for everything that comes with this package. I still don't understand where else would I have posted it and what other details would I have provided to make it clearer. Please guide me rather than giving a negative reputation point.

Comment: I didn't vote you down. I gave you quite a lot of tasks and questions to be answered. Now it's your turn to edit your question or even better ask it as support request on drupal.org. And note: **Never ever hack core or contrib files!**

Comment: So should I ask this question on Drupal community forums? But I saw many similar questions here dated back couple of years that were answered. If this question does not fit here, what type of questions shall I ask on this platform?

Comment: Please don't post links to dev, stage or prod sites as they have no value as soon as your issue got fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103044/discussion-between-leymannx-and-efe).